# Woodstox default entities replaced

Tags: entity, woodstox

I have the following tag in a webservice xml response:
<text>&quot;&gt;&lt;&amp;</text>

And this is reported in my characters method as "><&, but I need to be reported as it is (&quot;&gt;&lt;&amp;).

I've set XMLInputFactory.IS_REPLACING_ENTITY_REFERENCES to Boolean.FALSE, but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Joan.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible with Woodstox. Handling of character entities, and pre-defined entities (lt, gt, amp, apos, quot) is automatic and is required of XML parsers.

There are some XML parsers that expose underlying raw buffer contents; I think `xpp3` does that. You could try it instead. But none of Stax implementations that I know of supports such access, nor SAX parsers.